# How to access the command line in adobe air

Tags: air

This might be something simple i just haven't picked up but what is the function where you can send commands directly to the command line (eg: command("ls") ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this directly. Have a look in this post for more information :

[Can Adobe AIR applications execute processes on the local client machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265265/can-adobe-air-applications-execute-processes-on-the-local-client-machine)