# adobe air - Is there anyway to get OS open a file, their native applications?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, air

In adobe air, is there anyway to get OS open a file, in their native applications?

What about in Flex 4?

Answer (score 3):

In AIR 1.5 there isn't any way to do it. But stay tuned ;)

=Ryan
ryan@adobe.com

Comment: You tease! Just tell us before MAX!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to checkout [StackOverflow Question 265265](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265265/can-adobe-air-applications-execute-processes-on-the-local-client-machine) - Can Adobe AIR applications execute processes on the local client machine?

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use something like this:

```
var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath('Yodl_RBI.ppt.zip');
navigateToURL(new URLRequest(file.url));
```

It will normally open the asset in a browser window though, but for images and stuff that kind of works.

However if you point it to a folder it will typically open the folder containing the item, which is half way there...